# Any known ambiguity in MATH functions of Vb.net and C++

Tags: c++, vb.net, math

Recently I found that there is ambiguity in results of C++ **fmod** function and its equivalent **Math.IEEERemainder** in Vb.net

If we calculate **fmod(4.1887902053333335 / 6.283185307, 1.0)** in C++ we get,
0.6666666677277 while **Math.IEEERemainder(4.1887902053333335 / 6.283185307, 1.0)** in Vb.net results in -0.33333333322723 thus we find complete difference in results seriously affects output.

I am currently working on a project which has several mathematical operations including sine , hyperbolic cosine, modulus etc. which is originally in C++ and I am tasked to convert it in Vb.net.

While most of the code can simply be pulled in and out of online converters on web these mathematical ambiguities remain hidden damaging the result.

Does anyone here know of such known differences especially for Math class in Vb.net with respect to C++?

Comment: The C++ counterpart of `IEEERemainder` is [`std::remainder`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder), not `std::fmod`.

Comment: Any good standard adds one more way to do the same thing.  You'll like `4.1887902053333335 / 6.283185307 mod 1.0` better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [doc on Math.IEEERemainder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ieeeremainder(v=vs.110).aspx) says the following:

> The IEEERemainder method is not the same as the modulus operator. Although both return the remainder after division, the formulas they use are different. The formula for the IEEERemainder method is:
>
> IEEERemainder = dividend - (divisor * Math.Round(dividend / divisor))
>
> In contrast, the formula for the modulus operator is:
>
> Modulus = (Math.Abs(dividend) - (Math.Abs(divisor) * 
>             (Math.Floor(Math.Abs(dividend) / Math.Abs(divisor))))) * 
>             Math.Sign(dividend)

So, it's just a different function.

Comment: thanks for the insight in documentation, anything else like this you know at contrast regarding different formulas implemented in these languages?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that VB.NET uses ["Bankers' rounding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) if you convert floating point numbers to integral numbers, so `CInt(3.5)` is `(int)round(3.5)`, both `4`, not just `(int)3.5`, which is `CInt(Math.Floor(3.5))`, both `3`.